# Deleting Directory at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I just want to delete the `Directory` which is in the `project folder`.

That folder having all web `sharing authority and permission`.

The problem is arising when i am `deleting the folder`.

Folder is deleted from the `serverpath(Virtual Directory)`.

But my problem is that when i complete my task and click on any control it will redirect me to the `Login page` with the `return url`  as there is a `secure authentication` on the root directory is available

Comment: I really don't understand your question.  Can you rephrase that last sentence?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Application domain recycled when
>   Sub-Directories are deleted, that's why your session will lost and you are redirected to the login page.

For more details, check this article from MSDN Blog and read **Why does an application domain recycle?** from here
[ASP.NET Case Study: Lost session variables and appdomain recycles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx)

and also check this one [Deleting ASP.NET 2.0 Application Sub-Directories Shuts Down the AppDomain](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toddca/archive/2006/07/17/668412.aspx)

Comment: thanks Akhtar i understand the Problem But Can You tell me the Solution of this .How can i Overcome from this situation

Answer (score 6):

As noted in another answer, this is because the web app is restarted whenever you delete a folder inside the web app's directory structure (i.e. below the web app's root directory).

The only solution I found for this problem is to move the data directories (which you create/delete/modify) outside the web app's root directory / virtual directory.

Then we create a link (junction) in the file system so that the directory appears to be inside the virtual directory. This prevents ASP.NET from monitoring the data directory for delete operations.

Example:

- Our web site (virtual directory) is located at `C:\projectX\website`
- the data directory (where we create/delete files and folders) is located at `C:\projectX\data`
- then we create a link which makes the data folder available as `C:\projectX\website\data`

The link is created using the program `Linkd.exe` (available in the windows resource kit), with the following command:

```
linkd c:\projectX\website\data c:\projectX\data
```

Now `C:\projectX\website\data` is a link/junction which points to the real data directory. Inside your web app, you can continue working as if the data directory were a physical directory below the web app's root directory.

E.g. in your web site you can access the data folder using this code:

```
Server.MapPath("~/data")
```

And you can also used the windows file explorer and browse to C:\projectX\website\data. It appears just like a real directory.

As you can see, you can continue to use the linked data folder as if it were a normal folder inside the web app's directory. The only difference is that ASP.NET will not track the directory for delete operations and will therefore not restart the application. This means, you can now create/delete/modify folders and files inside the `~/data` directory as you wish, without having the web app restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace folder from the project root into the App_Data folder?